# Не работает добавление в автозагрузку с помощью WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi

Добавляю в автозагрузку файл, всё добавляется и показывается в диспетчере задач. Но вот проблема: в диспетчере показывается статус "Отключено", из-за чего автозапуска не происходит. Вот код:

```
HKEY hKey; 
char szPath[] = "\"path\\to\\program\"";
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
             "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 
             NULL, 
             "", 
             REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, 
             KEY_SET_VALUE, 
             NULL, 
             &hKey,
             NULL);

if (hKey) 
{ 
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, "some program", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, sizeof(szPath) + 1); 
    RegCloseKey(hKey); 
}
```

Comment: Потому что читайте обновления Windows.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/take-control-of-your-windows-start-up-237022a3-36b0-5207-b9be-9c9d8962f19c

Comment: И что я должен был узнать из этой статьи? И тем более, такие программы как Steam, Opera и т.д. всё таки добавляются в автозагрузку. Вы мне не дали ответа, за которым на этот ресурс и приходят.

Comment: @omegalul попробуйте писать не в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, а в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` и проверьте путь, должен быть полный путь к exe

Comment: Путь получаю через GetModuleName, в HKEY_CURRENT_USER то же самое.